# How to properly handle database queries without freezing the UI?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

FIRST! I know very similar questions have been asked before, however, the answers have been so case specific that I seriously don't understand how to apply them. Please don't roast me.

All I want is to build a rather generic application that has CRUD modules and reporting (c# and MySQL), nothing special. However, everytime my app runs a line where there is a call to a method that queries the server the UI freezes a few ms, the freeze-like-stuttering of the UI feels incredibly annoying.

As I understood, every DB call needs to be done in a different thread with a background worker or a task so the main thread doesn't get busy and makes the UI unresponsive BUT whenever I try to do this I have issues because I can't access the UI components.

Can you guys help me with this simple login form as an example, please?

I have a simple form, 2 textboxes, txtUser and txtPassword and a button with the following code:

```
    MySqlDataReader? user = MdlUsers.GetUserByUsername(txtUser.Text);
    if (user != null && user.Read())
    {
        string? pwd = user["clave"].ToString();
        if (pwd != null && pwd.Equals(txtPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Acceso correcto.");
            logged = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Acceso denegado.");
            logged = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No regresó nada.");
        logged = true;
    }
```

This is the code to the MdlUser class:

```
public class MdlUsers
    {
        public static MySqlDataReader? GetUserByUsername(string username)
        {
            MySqlDataReader? result = null;
            try
            {
                string qry = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = @username";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, MdlConnection.Connect());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I click the button the UI stutters. So how can I handle this? Thank you very much.

Comment: By using Tasks + async/await also DbCommand has async methods same as DbDataReader

Comment: @Selvin yes, that's what I read, but I don't get how to apply them in the code i provided.

Comment: `async Task<(bool Succes, string Message)> TryLogin(string login, string password) {`  ... no message boxes just return `(true, "ok")` or `(false, "reason why fail")` `}` would be nice start then replace `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()` and `user.ReadAsync()` ... finally in on click make it `async void` and do `var result =  await TryLogin(....)` then based on result show message

Comment: @Selvin, alright! thank you, managed to make it work like that. One question though, I feel like it's better to have specific classes for the return type of Task with all the information i need (when i need to get, say, all the user information) to get back, is that good practice? or should i just make it Task<MySqlDataReader> ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: good practice is to not pass database specific classes to UI ... just make "service" which can do what you ask and work without GUI... also yes, specific class for result would be good (yeah something lag LoginResult would be nice)... I use ValueTuple just because I don't wana make comment longer :D

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle any situation of that sort is to perform your long blocking operation on a separate task, and when it finishes, ***post*** a call to the GUI thread.

You have not told us what kind of GUI you are using, (that's what tags are for on stackoverflow,) I suspect it is  WinForms, so the way to do this in WinForms is with `Control.BeginInvoke()`.

When you specify an `Action` to be invoked with `Control.BeginInvoke()`, that `Action` will run in the GUI thread, so it will be able to safely "access the UI components."

Comment: You are right, I completely forgot about that, sorry. Yes, it is WinForms. How would you implement Control.BeginInvoke() in my code?

Comment: At the end of your task, use `Control.BeginInvoke()` to supply your control with the result of the task.